# How to show hidden element with link to its anchor?

Tags: jquery

I have tabbed menu with this code:

```
$('#menu').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // Use the first link as the initial active tab
    $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        $("#tab1").show();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Issue is about a direct link to a tab (for example, site.com/#tab2)—it doesn't work. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: @VIDesignz I have used code from this tutorial:  http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs.

Comment: I take it you are trying to get a tab to show when the user comes from a different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this....

[Working Example](http://videsignz.com/tab.html)

Add to your Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = $(location).attr('href').replace( 'http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.html' , "");
$('a[href="' + x + '"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your tabs a unique `id` attribute.  eg:

```
<div id="menu">
   <div id="tab1">...</div>
   <div id="tab2">...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

make a generic function for showing a tab, given the tab's id:

```
function showTab(tabId) {

    // find the requested tab using the given id
    var tab = $(tabId);

    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content

    $active = tab;
    $content = $(tab.attr('href'));

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();

    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Use the `hashchange` event to show the proper tab whenever the hash changes:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() { 
    showTab(location.href);
});
```

rewrite your click handler to use the showTab method too:

```
$(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    showTab($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

When the page loads initially, select the proper tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showTab(location.href);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Lee. However, I got a little bit easier answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13225777/1447182.